# Drawing the default inspector with UIElements/UI Builder

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a `LevelEditor` script which has a custom inspector editor built with UIBuilder and UIElements.
The problem is that i would like to cache references inside a list but i do not want to make a custom list view for it (it's kinda hard to implement in UIElements and not worth the time) so i thought i would just make the `private List<MyType> _myVar;` as `[Serializefield]` and then draw the **DefaultInspector** below the custom one.

I found a method that does this [DrawDefaultInspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.DrawDefaultInspector.html) but unfortunately it does nothing.

```
public override VisualElement CreateInspectorGUI()
{
    _visualTree.CloneTree(_rootElement);

    // My custom editor code
    ...

    DrawDefaultInspector();

    return _rootElement;
}
```

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to place an `IMGUIContainer` via **UIBuilder** (or by code via `_rootElement.Add(IMGUIVisualElement)`) and than do the following inside `CreateInspectorGUI`

```cs
public override VisualElement CreateInspectorGUI()
{
    _visualTree.CloneTree(_rootElement);

    // Your custom editor code
    ...

    // Drawing the default inspector
    var defaultInspector = _rootElement.Q<IMGUIContainer>();
    defaultInspector.onGUIHandler = () => DrawDefaultInspector();

    return _rootElement;
}
```

What i usually do is placing the `DefaultInspector` in a foldout too so designers can use the custom Inspector but whenever they need some advanced stuff that ain't visible to them they can use the default inspector.

So a layout like this will appear to them (default inspector is hidden by default ofc :) )
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Be careful, the accepted answer showing the trick with `DrawDefaultInspector` seems to be obsolete in the newer versions¹ of Unity, which use UIElements by default in the inspector window.

The standard way to insert the default inspector is by populating a `VisualElement` with the controls. The code below show how you do that:

```cs
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
using UnityEditor.UIElements;

...

VisualElement defaultInspector = new VisualElement();
InspectorElement.FillDefaultInspector(defaultInspector, serializedObject, this);
// "this" is the Editor itself
```

Now you have a populated `defaultInspector` element which you can return as the root element, add elements to it, or add it to the root element. I myself would recommend to add it to the root element, but I have no strong reason for that.

¹I am not sure which version started to use it, or how is it implemented internally by now, but the [official docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.2/Documentation/Manual/UIE-HowTo-CreateCustomInspector.html) recommends this way starting from 2021.3.

Comment: Won't this this method use UI toolkit to draw the default inspector though? It may be better to use IMGUI Container because many packages still use IMGUI for custom property drawers.

Comment: I don't think it is better to use IMGUIContainer, Unity handle this internally. Until now I had no problem with retrocompatibility, but I cannot confirm it works for all cases. By using IMGUIContainer I guess you lose the performance improvements. Unity has set UI toolkit as the default inspector mode. Unless you set it explicitly back to IMGUI, I think it's better to use the new workflow. Of course nothing prevents one from using the IMGUIContainer, it's just not the recommended way from the docs.